# Operating systems-unexpected output

Tags: c, operating-system

I am having trouble with a program where my `client.c` reads the informations provided by the user (2 integers and the character `"+"` or `"-"`). Then using the `execl` system call, `client.c` transmits the user input to `server.c` where the sum or the difference between the two integers is calculated. Finally, the result will be transmitted to the `client.c` with the `exit` system call and `client.c` will print that result.

The problem I'm facing here is that I'm not getting the result I expect (it always prints 0) and I can't figure it out why.

**client.c**

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define MAXLINE 1024
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char buf1[MAXLINE];
    char buf2[MAXLINE];
    char buf3[MAXLINE];
    int childPid;
    pid_t pid;
    int status;
    int x,i,j,n;
    char c;
    x=1;
    n=0;
        while(x<=3){
        printf(">");

         if(x==1){
         fgets(buf1, MAXLINE, stdin);
         if(sscanf(buf1,"%i",&i)!=1){
            perror("eroare la citire i");
         }}
         if(x==2){
         fgets(buf2, MAXLINE, stdin);
         if(sscanf(buf2,"%i",&j)!=1){
         perror("eroare la citire j");}}
         if(x==3){
         fgets(buf3, MAXLINE, stdin);
         if(sscanf(buf3,"%c",&c)!=1){
         perror("eroare la citire c");}}
          x++;
          }
        if ((pid=fork()) < 0) {
            perror("Eroare fork");
            exit(1);
                }
         else if (pid == 0) {
         n=execl("/home/mihaelavasiu/so/SO-lab6/Problem1_2/bin/Debug/Porblem1_2",buf1,buf2,buf3,NULL);
         wait(&status);
        }
printf("%d" ,status);

}
```

**server.c**

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int arc,char **argv)
{
    int x,y,result;
    char c;
    if(sscanf(argv[1],"%i",&x)!=1){
        perror("eroare la citirea primului argument");

    }
    if(sscanf(argv[2],"%i",&y)!=1){
        perror("eroare la citirea celui de-al argument");

    }
    if(sscanf(argv[3],"%c",&c)!=1){
        perror("eroare la citirea celui de-al treilea argument");

    }
    if(c=='+')
        result=x+y;
    if(c=='-')
        result=x-y;
    printf("%d",result);
    exit(result);
}
```

Comment: You should do some debugging.

Comment: As Oliver says, do some debugging. **GDB** is your friend.

Comment: You never `wait` for the child process in the parent process. If you had some better indentation it would be very noticeable.

Comment: Which language are you using, C or C++?  They are different languages, for example the C++ language has `std::getline` and `std::string` which the C language doesn't.  Adjust your tags appropriately.

Comment: It might help if you actually sent the `'+'` or the `'-'` to the server by sending `c` instead of `x`.

Comment: I didin't realise that i was using "x" insead of "c"...But, i am still getting 0 no matter what integers i use. I thought i'm not using well the "wait" system call, but it's the only way i found.

Comment: `execl` does not work like that: it's no use just passing numbers, you have to pass string pointers. Do you have the compiler warnings enabled?

Comment: You really need to read all the compiler warnings the compiler tells you, and also tell it to issue *more* warnings by using e.g. `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` when compiling. The compiler is good at detecting things that will lead to *undefined behavior*, or other "weird" things you might do that is technically okay but will probably not work as expected. And remember, using casting to silence warnings is almost never the correct solution.

Comment: I am testing the program using the terminal, but i'm not getting any warnings even though,with your help, i realized  that i was not using buffers when i called "execl" and, after these changes it seems like nothing chaged.

Comment: "Even" MSVC gives *"warning C4047: 'function' : 'const char *' differs in levels of indirection from 'int'"* when an `int` is passed to `execl`. And have you tried some basic debugging, such as printing the program arguments in `argv`?

Comment: I made some debugging using Code::blocks and now i am getting this error:"eroare la citirea celui de-al doilea argument" wich is's used in server.c so the error must be with the parameters but I have no idea how else I could transmit them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your calling `execl` with the wrong number of arguments.

From the `execl` `man`:

> The const char *arg and subsequent ellipses in the execl(), execlp(),
>   and execle() functions can be thought of as arg0, arg1, ..., argn.
>   Together they describe a list of one or more pointers to
>   null-terminated strings that represent the argument list available to
>   the executed program. ***The first argument, by convention, should point
>   to the filename associated with the file being executed.*** The list of
>   arguments must be terminated by a NULL pointer, and, since these are
>   variadic functions, this pointer must be cast (char *) NULL.

In addition to passing in the path to your executable the argument list should start with the name of the file being executed.  A call would be in the form `execl("/path", "filename", "arg1", "arg2", ...)`

Instead of:

```
n=execl("/home/mihaelavasiu/so/SO-lab6/Problem1_2/bin/Debug/Porblem1_2",buf1,buf2,buf3,NULL);
```

should be:

```
n=execl("/home/mihaelavasiu/so/SO-lab6/Problem1_2/bin/Debug/Porblem1_2","Porblem1_2",buf1,buf2,buf3,NULL);
```

Notice that `"Porblem1_2"` is given right after the path to it.

Also, the way you're using `wait` to deliver the "result" won't work the way I think you're expecting it to, bit-shift with `status >> 8`.

Comment: Thank you very much. I would never figure it out... Calling exec this way I'm getting the right result.

Comment: @user5642508 then please "accept" this answer if it solved your problem. That's how StackOverflow works.